# How to mount disk in terminal?

Tags: release-freya

I know, I must mount disk to install. I'm too lazy to do this by hands. Can I do this from the terminal?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question - It's not clear what you are referring to with "mount disk to install". Are you talking about the system installation?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Google is your friend before posting to Stack Exchange
To mount a CD / DVD from the terminal type : `mount -t iso9660 /dev/scd0 /media/cdrom`
To mount a partition from the terminal type : `mkdir ~/mypartition/` and  `mount -t auto -v /dev/sda1 ~/mypartition` (replace sda1 with your partition)

To mount an ISO image from the terminal type :`mkdir ~/iso` and  `sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop "/path/to/iso.iso" ~/iso`

Also remember that a disk is a hard drive or SSD and a disc is a CD / DVD